# Finding Correlation coefficient from ANOVA/regression

Tags: regression, correlation, anova

How would you find the correlation coefficient from given Sum of Squares values (Regression and Error) and regression values - slope of the estimate and standard error?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Results from simple linear regression or multiple linear regression?

Comment: Single linear regression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple linear regression, the regression coefficient and correlation coefficient have following relation (when sum of square (SS) due to regression and error are know).

correlation coefficient = sign(slope) * sqrt[SS(regression)/SS(Total)]

SS(Total) = SS(regression)+SS(Error).

sign(slope) = 1 if slope >0. = -1 if slope < 0, and =0 if slope = 0.